# Subdomain for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have a website on `www.example.com` powered by wordpress. I want to make the blog articles only accessible from `blog.example.com`, so `blog.example.com/article-1` would work, but `www.example.com/article-1` wouldn't with a 404 error.

What I did so far is add a CNAME entry for `blog.example.com` to `example.com`, the problem i have now is that the article would be accessible from both *www* and the *blog* subdomain. How can i do this with the same wordpress installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is called WordPress Multisite.
Here you go with the instructions:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/creating-a-network-to-enable-wordpress-multisite/
http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-enable-multisite/#.VYepDkbh1N4

Comment: sure? seems like an overkill, is this the only way?

Comment: I am sure, I found a similiar question to yours: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135901/how-can-i-run-the-same-wordpress-install-on-multiple-subdomains